# How can I randomly choose between multiple print commands?

Tags: python, list, random, printing

How can I randomly choose between multiple print commands?

For instance...

I want to randomly choose one of these two print functions...

```
print ('The ball ', (random.choice (action_ball))
print ('The cat', (random.choice (action_cat))
```

then reference these two lists...

```
action_ball = ['rolled','bounced']
action_cat = ['purred','meowed']
```

to randomly generate one of these four sentences...

```
the ball rolled
the ball bounced
the cat purred
the cat meowed
```

I understand how to generate from one list:

```
import random
action_ball = ['rolled','bounced']
print ('The ball ', (random.choice (action_ball))
```

After that, I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from random import randint, choice

ball_choices = ['rolled', 'bounced']
cat_choices = ['purred', 'meowed']

if randint(0, 1):
    print ('The ball ', choice(ball_choices))
else:
    print ('The cat', choice(cat_choices))
```

This randomly generates a 0 or 1, if 1, it then prints the randomly chosen ball string, if 0, it prints the randomly chosen cat string. Does that make sense?

*Edit: If you wanted to add more choices, you can always change the range of `randint()`, and have conditionals for each, but this can be generalized very easily (saving you a lot of typing) like so:*

```py
options = {
    'ball': ['rolled', 'bounced'],
    'cat': ['purred', 'meowed'],
    'tv': ['turned on', 'turned off', 'exploded'],
    # Add more here...
}

# Pick a random item from the keys of options
random_item = choice(list(options))

# Print the item and choose randomly from that option's choices
print('The', random_item, choice(options[random_item]))
```

Now, additional choices and options can be added by just adding more entries to `options`.

Comment: Thanks. It does. And, adding choices would mean increasing the "randint" range and adding more "else" statements?

Comment: Sure, you could increase the range of `randint()`, or you could do another 'choice' and use that choice (I think that's a bit more intuitive). I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all four sentences up front and subsequently just choose one of them:

```py
from random import choice
src = [('The ball',('rolled','bounced')),('The cat',('purred','meowed'))]
all = [sentence[0] + ' ' + word for sentence in src for word in sentence[1]]

for _ in range(5):   # arbitrary number of repetitions
    print(choice(all))
```

Comment: Might be worth noting this has substantial overhead as your number of options increases.

Comment: Thanks for this.